# Screen Overlay Detected, Permission problem

Tags: applications, settings, permissions

I keep getting this dialog that says "Screen Overlay detected" that basically tells me to turn of the screen overlay in order to proceed with the change in the permission settings of the apps. I have gone to settings and turned off all of the screen overlays but I keep getting this problem.

I would really love it if anyone could help me by telling me what to do so I can be able to make changes in the permission of my apps! Please Help!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and it turned out that this was caused by Messenger's Chat Head. Maybe you have it opened?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happens because of my blue screen filter app. Simply pause any such app and then give the permissions.